# Im troubled by an exercise about finding suborders of a given order in a set.

Tags: order-theory

The exercise is to find sub-orders of $(P( \lbrace x,y,z \rbrace ), \subset)$ such they are:
(1)Total ordered, (2) partial ordered and not total , (3) partial but not well ordered.

First of all , $P(\lbrace x,y,z \rbrace)=  \lbrace \emptyset ,\lbrace x\rbrace ,\lbrace y \rbrace , \lbrace z \rbrace ,\lbrace x,y\rbrace ,\lbrace x,z \rbrace ,\lbrace y,z \rbrace ,A \rbrace$

So , by a total order I thought of $\lbrace\lbrace x \rbrace , \lbrace x,y \rbrace , \lbrace x,y,z \rbrace \rbrace$ since it is antysimetric, transitive and total .
For a partial  order but not total o thought of $\lbrace \lbrace x \rbrace \lbrace y \rbrace \lbrace x,y \rbrace , \lbrace x,y,z \rbrace  \rbrace $ since it is partial but we can not compare $\lbrace x \rbrace$ and $\lbrace y \rbrace $ . Does my examples are right? how do I show a partial order that is not well ordered?? Thanks

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$ in $\{\{a\}\{b\}\{x,y\},\{x,y,z\}\}$? You want a sub-order, and $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are not in the orginal order.

Comment: Can you show that a well order is a total order? :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry I meant $\lbrace x \rbrace$ and $\lbrace y \rbrace$.

Comment: @Mingus But I just want to construct 3 examples of  (1) , (2) and (3). Dont know if the examples I give for (1) and (2) are right , also I dont know how to give an example for (3)?

Comment: @Fis The examples you gave for (1) and (2) are correct. For (3) think about my first comment and also notice every finite total order is a well order. (And you only have a finite amount of elements here...)

Comment: @Mingus Got it! Thank u . :)